# How to change the size of arrows in VTK?

Tags: c++, data-visualization, vtk

Short question but is there a function/way of easily changing the sizes of arrows in VTK C++?

I want to do this because I am trying to display a set of arrows all in specific positions that are pretty close to each other but because I can't change the arrow size, the output looks really messy.

At the moment I am using the arrow source objects, adding them to unique actors and then iteratively adding them to the renderer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to [scale the vtkActor](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkProp3D.html#a23d90121c55a3922632e7dd18e4dff02) using something to the likes of myActor.SetScale(0.5). If all goes well this should scale your arrow size without changing anything else.

Comment: Thanks. I might try that out. I also found that you could possibly use a        vtkTransform and transformFilter and scale it using this and that seems to work but your suggestion might be a better option so I will have a look at it

Comment: Doesn't work, the whole arrow gets scaled, not just the length.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the *length* of vtkArrowSource, you should set the x-scale dimension of the actor.

When adding an vtkArrowSource:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkArrowSource> arrowSource = vtkSmartPointer<vtkArrowSource>::New();
arrowSource->SetShaftRadius(0.05);
arrowSource->SetTipRadius(0.1);
arrowSource->SetTipLength(0.3);

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
mapper->SetInputConnection(arrowSource->GetOutputPort());
vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
actor->SetMapper(mapper);
```

The magic:

```
double scale[3] = { 10, 1, 1 }; // Set x-scale to 10, y and z unchanged (1)
actor->SetScale(scale);
```

**Note**: This stretches the arrow tip as well!
I fixed that by setting

```
arrowSource->SetTipLength(0.3 / 10); // Scales arrow tip down by factor 10
```

Replace the two occurrences of 10 by a variable to parametrize it.